# Expand and collapse table rows is messing up the background row color

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I have a simple script to expand and collapse my table rows

```
<script>
    $('.header').click(function(){
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-minus-square-o fa-plus-square-o');
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100, function(){
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is my HTML code for the table

```
<table class="table compare-table">
  <thead>
    <th class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left scroll-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
    <th>
        <span><a class="remove-item"><i class="fa fa-close iconBasefont"></i> Remove</a></span>
        <h6 class="no-margin-b">Johanson</h6>
        <h4 class="nomargins">202R18W102KV4E</h4>
    </th>
    <th>
        <span><a class="remove-item"><i class="fa fa-close iconBasefont"></i> Remove</a></span>
        <h6 class="no-margin-b">Samsung</h6>
        <h4 class="nomargins">  CL10A225MP8NNNC</h4>
    </th>
    <th>
        <span><a class="remove-item"><i class="fa fa-close iconBasefont"></i> Remove</a></span>
        <h6 class="no-margin-b">Murata</h6>
        <h4 class="nomargins">  GRM188R61A225ME34D</h4>
    </th>
    <th>
        <span><a class="remove-item"><i class="fa fa-close iconBasefont"></i> Remove</a></span>
        <h6 class="no-margin-b">TDK</h6>
        <h4 class="nomargins">  C1608X5R1A225M</h4>
    </th>
    <th class="text-left"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right scroll-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
  </thead>
  <tr class="header">
      <th colspan="6"><i class="fa fa-minus-square-o"></i> General Information </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Part desc</td>
    <td>Part desc</td>
    <td>Part desc</td>
    <td>Part desc</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Datasheet</td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr  class="header">
    <th colspan="6"><i class="fa fa-minus-square-o"></i> Electrical Information </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some details</td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Another Attribute</td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Datasheet</td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Another Attribute</td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Another Attribute</td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pdf-file"></i> <a href="#">Datasheet</a></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And below is my css for table row background

```
.compare-table{
  tr{
    td:first-child{
        border-right:3px solid #e0e0e0!important;
    }
    &:first-child{
    background-color: #fff;
    }
    &:nth-of-type(odd){
    background-color: #fff;
    }
    &:nth-of-type(even){
    background-color:#F5F5F5;
    }
    &.header{
    background: #E9F3FF!important;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #4A90E2;
     cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, the issue I am facing is whenever the row headers in-between the table is expanded or collapsed the background color is getting messed up.

[image]

Comment: I don't see any problems: https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/r7x15L7t/

Comment: Thanks @Gerard Now if you look at my second image in the screenshot thats the problem. Its strange that JSfiddle shows no problem :( Any thoughts?

Comment: I assume you have more code running when you made the screenshot but I don't know how much. I can't see anything weird in the code provided.

Comment: Alright. May be there should be a way to close this question then. Thanks for your time for taking a look at this. But the same problem persists on my local. Unable to figure it out.